# Storing Credentials in Authentication Server made using Java libraries for unit testing

Tags: java, authentication, http-authentication

I have created the Authentication Server using Java.. I want to know how should I store the credentials of the users in my server so that I can perform the Authentication in the fastest and the best way.

Comment: What did your research tell you?

Comment: I searched on internet and found some solution related to indexing.. but didnt find too useful.. I am confused which data structure should I use

Comment: We need more detail. Will the AuthServer be provided with String userNames? Oder numeric ids? ... Are you expecting 10 auths/s or more like a million/s ... Are you planning on using some DB like Redis or others? How many Credentials is the server expected to hold overall?

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: @Michael thanks for your answer.. actually I made this authentication for testing purpose using sun libraries in java . I created this to create a unit test for my login controller.

Comment: It was not clear from you question

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention testing part.. will do so now..

Answer (score 0):

- Store a user name as the plain text.
- Store a user password in the hashed way using SA256 or SHA512
- For each user generate salt that will be used for hashing of the password for the user and store it in DB (each user has its own salt).

During authentication hash the password that you get from a user in the plain text using the same salt and compare to the stored password.